# Is it possible to specify more than one column for the merge in pandas (python)?

Tags: python, pandas

I want to merge two tables, A and B. Table A has values in one column, in B these are spread amongst two columns:

```
A
1   2   3
X   X   HH
Y   D   HD


B
1   2
HD  NaN
Nan HH
```

I tried with no success:

newTable = pd.merge(A, B, how='left', left_on = 3, right_on = 1, 2)

The doc speaks of column nameS for left_on and righ_on, so I assume it is possible? How?
http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/dev/merging.html

Comment: are columns in B mutually exclusive? if so, you can create a third column and use that to merge

Comment: Yes, they are! You mean, merge B1 and B2 first?

Comment: yes `B[1][pd.isnull(B[1])] = B[2][pd.isnull(B[1])]`

Comment: Another way to combine: `b['1'].combine_first(b['2'])`

Comment: @Zelazny7: that's better than the `max` hack.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you specify columns to join on, make sure to refer to them as strings. If you need to refer to two columns in your join, use a list of strings.

```
left_on = '3'
right_on = ['1', '2]
```

Comment: Its good practice to make your column names strings instead of integers, that being said you don't have to make them strings for a successful merge. You can also use the indicator option `newTable = pd.merge(A, B, how='left', left_on = [3], right_on = [1, 2], indicator=True)` which will create a `"_merge"` variable in the merged dataset which you can use to check which obs from each dataset merged.